# Linear Diophantine equation, Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: math, diophantine

suppose i want to find **any** value of x and y such that they satisfy `x . W + y . D = P`

this can be done by the following **using extended euclidean algorithm**

```
int exgcd(int a, int b, int &x, int &y)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
       x = 1;
       y = 0;
       return a;
    }
    int g, xi, yi;
    g = exgcd(b, a % b, xi, yi);
    x = yi;
    y = xi - (a / b * yi);
    return g;
}
```

but this will be just some random x and y satisfying the equation

suppose i add an additional constraint that i want any x y z such that

```
x>=0 y>=0 z>=0 and x + y + z = n
```

how can i effectively (please share code/pseudocode if possible) find all such x y and z??

my question boils down to find any x and y (using extended euclidean algorithm) which

1) satisfy a linear equation

2) fall in a given range

[here is the link to the question if you want](https://codeforces.com/contest/1244/problem/C)

Comment: Where is the z in equation?

Comment: you can find any value x and y such that their sum doesnt exceed n. this is is what i meant.

Comment: From what i understand there are 2 equations and 3 unknowns,  (x * Wins + y * Draw + z * Lost = points) and x+y+z=n; You have to reduce one variable probably by reducing one unknown you can solve the equation; you can maybe add a method to guess value of z then solve for x & y, This will result in worst time of n * complexity of solving the equation for x & y

Comment: yes thats what i am asking i iterate over all z from 0 to n but then hw do i get all x y correponding to a particular value of z?? like i know a random value satisfying equation ax+by = c now how do i get corresponding values of x and y such that x+y=n?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we have 2 equations and 3 unknowns, so doing some simple mathematics we can find the equations we need to solve

```
x * W + y * D + z * 0 = p
```

And

```
x + y + z = n
```

given

```
x,y,z >=0
```

So firstly we will reduce one unknown by looping through any one of the unknowns lets say z

We iterate through 0 - n for z and our new equations will be

```
x * w + y * d = p
```

And

```
x + y = m   { m is n - z for value of z in current iteration
```

Now we have 2 equations and 2 unknowns

So our solution for x and y can now be reduced by substituting x in first equation

Which makes it

```
(m - y) * w + y * d = p
```

This can be reduced to

```
y = (p - m * w) / (d - w)
```

and

```
x = m - y
```

You can stop at first value where x and y are integers